# How to set google protobuf repeated field in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, protocol-buffers, proto

For example, you have a google protobuf message Customer with repeated field like below.

```
message Customer {
  repeated int32 items = 1;
}
```

How do you set the repeated items field in javascript?

Answer (score 1):

To set the repeated field in javascript,

You can use either setItemsList or addItems methods.

> For example, to use setItemsList method
>
> ```
> let customer = new Customer();
> customer.setItemsList([12, 123, 1234]);
> ```
>
> It will set the value of items to the javascript array.

> Or for another example, to use addItems method
>
> ```
> let customer = new Customer();
> customer.addItems(123);
> ```
>
> It will append the value of 123 to the list of items in the message.

For more info, you can check out the [protobuf docs for repeated field in javascript](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/javascript-generated#repeated).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. @Henry Neo the documentation link is out of date.